# How can I store a file in GIT in such a way that it will not be tracked?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have an `.ini` file in my git repository. It is meant to be a default configuration file documenting possible keys for the user to set. I would like that a user cloning the repository get these defaults. However, later on, each of the users (developers) would modify the `.ini` according to their preferences. The repository also has a `.gitignore` file where the `.ini` is listed. The problem is that I don't know how to tell git not to track this file. What would be the right way to achieve this?

Comment: You can have something like a git-tracked `config.ini.tmpl` that holds the default config. The user could either copy it to `config.ini` themselves, or generate the latter by a git-tracked shell script if necessary. The copied/generated `config.ini` should be git-ignored.

Comment: I re-read you post few times and still not able to get my head around it. You want your `.ini` to be downloaded with clone but not tracked by git when developers modify it and try to push. You also said that you already have the `.ini` mentioned in your `.gitignore`. That should fulfil your requirement. Where's the problem then? Am I missing onto anything here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+ignore+changes+tracked+file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have users run `git update-index --skip-worktree my.ini`, probably as part of a setup script. They can undo this with `--no-skip-worktree` later, if they mean to push changes back.

However, using a template as per [@fluffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12232870/fluffy)'s comment is usually a better call. You could still have a setup script to make sure the template is instantiated.

As you've probably noticed already, `.gitignore` doesn't stop already-tracked files from being, well, tracked.